# line height rendering with google font

Tags: windows, macos, css

I have a line height issue regarding a google font, specifically josefin sans. In MAC Os the line-height is greater than in Windows OS, is there any fix for this, I need them to be the same because Im applying a bottom border. Here's a jfiddle of an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/qX3na/

```
h1 span.main {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 74px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <h1 class="clearfix">
            <span class="bottom">
                <span class="inner">    
                    <span class="left">&nbsp;</span> 
                    <span class="main">Company name</span> 
                    <span class="right">&nbsp;</span> 
                </span>
            </span>
        </h1>
```

Comment: What make you think the line height is different? I mean there is probably some visual difference (which?), but why would that depend on `line-height`, when you have set it explicitly? Did you inspect the computed `line-height` values using developer tools, and what were the results? (It is illogical to set `line-height` in `px` and `font-size` in `em`, and it may cause odd effects, but that’s probably not the issue here.)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I figured out it is a google font api problem, which doesn't manage correctly the different font extensions for each browser/os.

I solved it not using google font, but hosting the font and embedding it with fontquirrel [webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).